# Eclipse cannot add weblogic server

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

Why is Next button greyed even after I selected my weblogic server :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced same problem on the eclipse which i have downloaded from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. But I search and spend time but, only solution which i found is "**download eclipse from oracle site**". Oracle is supplying eclipse for development purpose, If you can download that you can find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html).

This eclipse has adapter included by default. It has latest version of weblogic server adapter. You just download it and  configure your existing work space and serer domain path. It will work as it is as normal eclipse.

Hope this will solve your problem.